# Web Service has random ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, exception, glassfish

I've heard there's a Java FileChannel bug, but I'm having this with a web service.

I get the following exception :

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end
(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:473)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer
(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0
(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:107)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:296)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:203)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:73)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:128)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:853)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:822)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1011)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:996)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:967)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:261)
at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:392)
```

At random times, I see it in my logs.
The thing is This happens right when my web service should return it's value. I have the following  code :

```
   cs = con.prepareCall (" { call charge_subscriber (?,?,?,?,?,?)} ");
   cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
   cs.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
   cs.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
   cs.setInt(1, anum);
   cs.setInt(2, product_id);
   cs.setString(3, identifier);
   cs.execute();
   resultCode = cs.getInt(4);
   resultMessage = cs.getString(5);
   transNo = cs.getLong(6);

System.out.println("\n ANUM            :  "+anum+
"\n Product ID              :  "+product_id+
"\n Identifier              :  "+identifier+
"\n resultCode              :  "+resultCode+
"\n resultMessage           :  "+resultMessage+
"\n transNo                 :  "+transNo);

return new ApiResponse(resultCode,resultMessage,transNo);

} catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception while charging : "+e.getMessage());
    }
       finally {
           if(!con.isClosed())
                con.close();
           con = null;
           if(cs != null)
            cs.close();
           cs = null;
           return new ApiResponse(resultCode,resultMessage,transNo);
   }
```

And right above the exception I see the println with the right data,with a couple of miliseconds difference, so the proccess seems to be working allright.

I've read that `ClosedByInterruptException` can be caused by thread interuption, so I checked my admin console (I'm using Glassfish) and it also seems to be ok, I've allowed 200 threads,timeout @ 900 seconds.

This web service works most of the time, sometimes it does that. The webservice itself is calling a procedure in an Oracle 11g database, I thought maybe it's related to some bottleneck it the database, but then it wouldn't have shown the println with the right data I guess, also the procedure does what it's suppoused to when this error occurs.

So my question is, what could this error be or how could I catch it? I tried catching it but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the stacktrace, the exception happens when you are writing the response.  This suggests that the real cause is either a networking issue or a client that is not reading the response.

In either case, the best thing to do is to allow the exception to propagate, or to catch it and abandon processing the request.  There is little chance of doing anything that will allow the server to send the response to the client.

Comment: Ok but how do I catch it? the above catch doesn't work and it still happens. my problem with the exception is that it already does the actions in the database and I want to rollback the procedure